Buttons disappearing after clicking


var audioPlayer = document.getElementById('audioPlayer');
var subtitleDisplay = document.getElementById('subtitleDisplay');
var subtitles = [];

var mediaRecorder = null;
var recordedChunks = [];
var currentSubtitleIndex = -1;
var lastHighlightedIndex = -1;


function parseSubtitleFile(data) {
  subtitles = [];
  var lines = data.split('\n');
  var index = 0;
  while (index < lines.length) {
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(lines[index]))) {
      var number = parseInt(lines[index]);
      index++;
      var times = lines[index].split(' --> ');
      var start = times[0].trim();
      var end = times[1].trim();
      index++;
      var text = [];
      while (index < lines.length && lines[index] !== '') {
        text.push(lines[index]);
        index++;
      }
      subtitles.push({
        order: number,
        start: start,
        end: end,
        sentence: text.join('\n').trim()
      });
    } else {
      index++;
    }
  }
}



audioPlayer.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
  var currentTime = audioPlayer.currentTime;
  highlightSubtitle(currentTime);
  if (mediaRecorder && currentSubtitleIndex >= 0) {
    var currentSubtitle = subtitles[currentSubtitleIndex];
    if (currentTime >= parseTime(currentSubtitle.start) && currentTime <= parseTime(currentSubtitle.end)) {
      // Recording is in progress
      return;
    } else {
      console.log("else")
      stopRecording();
      currentSubtitleIndex++;
      if (currentSubtitleIndex < subtitles.length) {
        var nextSubtitle = subtitles[currentSubtitleIndex];
        startRecording(parseTime(nextSubtitle.start));
      }
    }
  }
});

function displaySubtitles() {
  var subtitleText = subtitles.map(function(subtitle, index) {
    var button = '<button class="timeButton" data-start="' + subtitle.start + '">' + subtitle.start + '</button>';
    return button + ' ' + subtitle.sentence;
  }).join('<br><br>');
  subtitleDisplay.innerHTML = subtitleText;

  highlightSubtitle(audioPlayer.currentTime);
  scrollToHighlightedSubtitle();
}

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('timeButton')) {
    var startTime = event.target.dataset.start;
    audioPlayer.currentTime = parseTime(startTime);
  }
});


function formatTime(seconds) {
  var date = new Date(null);
  date.setSeconds(seconds);
  var result = date.toISOString().substr(11, 12);
  return result.replace('.', ',');
}

var isRecordingStarted = false;

function highlightSubtitle(currentTime) {
  var formattedTime = formatTime(currentTime);

  // Find the nearest subtitle to the current time
  var nearestIndex = -1;
  var minDifference = Infinity;
  for (var i = 0; i < subtitles.length; i++) {
    var starting = parseTime(subtitles[i].start);
    var end = parseTime(subtitles[i].end);
    var difference = Math.min(Math.abs(starting - currentTime), Math.abs(end - currentTime));
    if (difference < minDifference) {
      minDifference = difference;
      nearestIndex = i;
    } else {
      break; // No need to check further
    }
  }

  // Check if the highlighted subtitle has changed
  if (lastHighlightedIndex !== nearestIndex) {
    // Start a new recording only if recording has not been started for this subtitle
    if (!isRecordingStarted) {
      stopRecording();
      startRecording(parseTime(subtitles[nearestIndex].start));
      isRecordingStarted = true;
    }
  } else if (lastHighlightedIndex >= 0 && currentTime >= parseTime(subtitles[lastHighlightedIndex].end)) {
    // Stop recording when the current time exceeds the end time of the current subtitle
    stopRecording();
    isRecordingStarted = false;
  }

  // Update lastHighlightedIndex after the check
  lastHighlightedIndex = nearestIndex;

  // Check if the current highlight is still valid
  if (
    lastHighlightedIndex >= 0 &&
    formattedTime >= subtitles[lastHighlightedIndex].start &&
    formattedTime <= subtitles[lastHighlightedIndex].end
  ) {
    // No need to re-highlight
    return;
  }

  // Highlight the nearest subtitle
  var subtitleText = subtitles.map(function(subtitle, index) {
    if (index === nearestIndex) {
      return '<span class="highlighted" style="background-color: #E7E7DF;">' + subtitle.sentence + '</span>';
    } else {
      return subtitle.sentence;
    }
  }).join('<br><br>');

  subtitleDisplay.innerHTML = subtitleText;
}




function parseTime(timeString) {
  var parts = timeString.split(':');
  var hours = parseInt(parts[0]);
  var minutes = parseInt(parts[1]);
  var seconds = parseFloat(parts[2].replace(',', '.'));
  return hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds;
}

//Probably deals with opening the folder/file selector
document.getElementById('openSubtitleButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('fileInput').accept = '.srt';
  document.getElementById('fileInput').onchange = function(event) {
    var file = event.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
      parseSubtitleFile(event.target.result);
      displaySubtitles();
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
  };
  document.getElementById('fileInput').click();
});
document.getElementById('openAudioButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('fileInput').accept = 'audio/*, .m4b';
  document.getElementById('fileInput').onchange = function(event) {
    var file = event.target.files[0];
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    audioPlayer.src = url;
    audioPlayer.load();
  };
  document.getElementById('fileInput').click();
});

// Load audio bookmarked position if available
var bookmarkedTime = localStorage.getItem('bookmarkedTime');
if (bookmarkedTime) {
  audioPlayer.currentTime = parseFloat(bookmarkedTime);
}

audioPlayer.addEventListener('play', function() {
  startRecording();
});

audioPlayer.addEventListener('pause', function() {
  // Store bookmarked position when audio is paused
  localStorage.setItem('bookmarkedTime', audioPlayer.currentTime);
  scrollToHighlightedSubtitle(); // Scroll to the highlighted subtitle
  localStorage.setItem('bookmarkedSubtitleIndex', lastHighlightedIndex);
  stopRecording();

});

function scrollToHighlightedSubtitle() {
  var highlightedSubtitle = document.querySelector('.highlighted');
  if (highlightedSubtitle) {
    var rect = highlightedSubtitle.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (rect.top < 0 || rect.bottom > window.innerHeight) {
      highlightedSubtitle.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'instant',
        block: 'center'
      });
    }
  }
}

// Function to start recording audio
function startRecording() {
  console.log("start recording")
  recordedChunks = []; // Clear previously recorded chunks
  mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(audioPlayer.captureStream());
  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(event) {
    recordedChunks.push(event.data);
  };
  mediaRecorder.onstop = function() {
    // Do not save the recorded audio to file here
  };

  mediaRecorder.start();
}



// Function to stop recording audio
function stopRecording() {
  if (mediaRecorder) {
    mediaRecorder.stop();
    console.log("stop recording")
  }
}

document.getElementById('saveAudioButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  saveAudioToFile();
});

function saveAudioToFile() {
  if (recordedChunks.length === 0) {
    console.log('No recorded audio to save');
    return;
  }
  var blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
    type: 'audio/mp3'
  });
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = url;
  a.download = 'recorded_audio.mp3';
  a.click();
  recordedChunks = []; // Clear recordedChunks after saving
}





//Shortcuts
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.code === 'Space') {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default scrolling behavior
    if (audioPlayer.paused) {
      audioPlayer.play();
    } else {
      audioPlayer.pause();
    }
  }
});
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.code === 'ArrowRight') {
    // Forward 10 seconds
    audioPlayer.currentTime += 10;
  } else if (event.code === 'ArrowLeft') {
    // Rewind 10 seconds
    audioPlayer.currentTime -= 10;
  }
});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Audio Player with Subtitles</title>
  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Klee+One:wght@600&family=Noto+Serif+JP:wght@500&display=swap');
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: 'Klee One', cursive;
      font-weight: 600;
      background-color: rgb(239, 218, 194);
    }
    
    #controls {
      display: flex;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: rgb(239, 218, 194);
    }
    
    #subtitleInput,
    #audioInput {
      display: none;
    }
    
    #audioPlayer {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      justify-content: space-between;
      width: 22%;
      padding: 15px;
      display: block;
    }
    
    #subtitleDisplay {
      margin: 20px auto;
      width: 70%;
      max-width: 800px;
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 1.25;
    }
    
    #controls button {
      padding: 5px 10px;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
  </style>

  <div id="controls">
    <button id="openSubtitleButton">Import Subtitle</button><br>
    <button id="openAudioButton">Import Audio</button>
    <input type="file" id="fileInput" style="display: none;">
    <audio id="audioPlayer" controls></audio>
    <button id="saveAudioButton" style="position: fixed; bottom: 20px; right: 20px;">Save Audio</button>
  </div>
  <div id="subtitleDisplay"></div>
  <script src="audioPlayer.js"></script>

</body>

</html>



I'm creating a book reader for myself, using subtitles synced with audio, with a highlight on the sentence that is playing.
But the next step is troubling me: I need to have either a button, or clicking on the sentence themselves and have the audio playback time move to that sentence.
Each subtitle entry has its own start time, I want to use that.
So I created a button for every sentence in the book.
But when I click any of the buttons, after moving the audio to the correct timer, all of them disappear. Looking through similar questions, I think it could be something with the innerHTML but I can't figure a way around it.


function displaySubtitles() {
  var subtitleText = subtitles.map(function(subtitle, index) {
    var button = '<button class="timeButton" data-start="' + subtitle.start + '">' + subtitle.start + '</button>';
    return button + ' ' + subtitle.sentence;
  }).join('<br><br>');
  subtitleDisplay.innerHTML = subtitleText;

  highlightSubtitle(audioPlayer.currentTime);
  scrollToHighlightedSubtitle();
}

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('timeButton')) {
    var startTime = event.target.dataset.start;
    audioPlayer.currentTime = parseTime(startTime);
  }
});
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Klee One', cursive;
  font-weight: 600;
  background-color: rgb(239, 218, 194);
}

#controls {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(239, 218, 194);
}

#subtitleInput,
#audioInput {
  display: none;
}

#audioPlayer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 22%;
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
}

#subtitleDisplay {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 800px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.25;
}

#controls button {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
<div id="controls">
  <button id="openSubtitleButton">Import Subtitle</button><br>
  <button id="openAudioButton">Import Audio</button>
  <input type="file" id="fileInput" style="display: none;">
  <audio id="audioPlayer" controls></audio>
  <button id="saveAudioButton" style="position: fixed; bottom: 20px; right: 20px;">Save Audio</button>
</div>
<div id="subtitleDisplay"></div>
<script src="audioPlayer.js"></script>




please add a full reproducible example as a snippet

let me learn how to do it

@FlashThunder The snippet isn't working, some security error, I need to open both the audio and the text to make it work. Also lots of Prettify fetch failed:  {}.

@ITgoldman I think I managed to include my whole code in the first snippet, I apologize for how messy the post is it's my first time posting. To run locally you'd need any audio and second any .srt

Don't shy away from using more structural html, like:
<span>
  <button> time </button>
  <span> sentence </span>
</span>

For example the function to display subtitles:
function displaySubtitles() {
    var subtitleText = subtitles.map(function (subtitle, index) {
        var button = '<span class="parent" data-subtitle-index="' + index + '"><button class="timeButton" data-start="' + subtitle.start + '">' + subtitle.start + '</button>';
        return button + ' ' + '<span class="sentence">' + subtitle.sentence + '</span></span>';
    }).join('<br><br>');
    subtitleDisplay.innerHTML = subtitleText;
}

Now you can treat and manipulate each element without affecting or rewriting the html for all others. Indeed, now selecting element and highlighting it should be simple:
function highlightSubtitle(currentTime) {
    var formattedTime = currentTime

    // Find the nearest subtitle to the current time
    var nearestIndex = -1;
    var minDifference = Infinity;
    for (var i = 0; i < subtitles.length; i++) {
        var starting = parseTime(subtitles[i].start);
        var end = parseTime(subtitles[i].end);
        var difference = Math.min(Math.abs(starting - currentTime), Math.abs(end - currentTime));
        if (difference < minDifference) {
            minDifference = difference;
            nearestIndex = i;
        } else {
            break; // No need to check further
        }
    }

    // Highlight the nearest subtitle
    var element = subtitleDisplay.querySelector("[data-subtitle-index='" + nearestIndex + "'] .sentence")
    element.classList.add("highlight")
    
}

Here's a working example which is based on your code.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Audio Player with Subtitles</title>
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Klee+One:wght@600&family=Noto+Serif+JP:wght@500&display=swap');
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: 'Klee One', cursive;
            font-weight: 600;
            background-color: rgb(239, 218, 194);
        }

        #controls {
            display: flex;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: rgb(239, 218, 194);
        }

        #subtitleInput,
        #audioInput {
            display: none;
        }

        #audioPlayer {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            justify-content: space-between;
            width: 22%;
            padding: 15px;
            display: block;
        }

        #subtitleDisplay {
            margin: 20px auto;
            width: 70%;
            max-width: 800px;
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 1.25;
        }

        #controls button {
            padding: 5px 10px;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }

        .highlight {
            background: red;

        }
    </style>

    <div id="controls">
        <button id="openSubtitleButton">Import Subtitle</button><br>
        <button id="openAudioButton">Import Audio</button>
        <input type="file" id="fileInput" style="display: none;">
        <audio id="audioPlayer" controls></audio>
        <button id="saveAudioButton" style="position: fixed; bottom: 20px; right: 20px;">Save Audio</button>
    </div>
    <div id="subtitleDisplay"></div>

</body>

</html>

<script>
    var audioPlayer = document.getElementById('audioPlayer');
    var subtitleDisplay = document.getElementById('subtitleDisplay');
    var subtitles = [
        { start: 12, sentence: "hello world sentence 1" },
        { start: 24, sentence: "hello world sentence 2" },
        { start: 36, sentence: "hello world sentence 3" },
        { start: 48, sentence: "hello world sentence 4" },
        { start: 60, sentence: "hello world sentence 5" },
    ].map(item => { item.end = item.start + 8; return item })



    var mediaRecorder = null;
    var recordedChunks = [];
    var currentSubtitleIndex = -1;
    var lastHighlightedIndex = -1;


    const parseTime = (time) => time

    function displaySubtitles() {
        var subtitleText = subtitles.map(function (subtitle, index) {
            var button = '<span class="parent" data-subtitle-index="' + index + '"><button class="timeButton" data-start="' + subtitle.start + '">' + subtitle.start + '</button>';
            return button + ' ' + '<span class="sentence">' + subtitle.sentence + '</span></span>';
        }).join('<br><br>');
        subtitleDisplay.innerHTML = subtitleText;
    }

    document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        if (event.target.classList.contains('timeButton')) {
            var startTime = event.target.dataset.start;
            highlightSubtitle(startTime)
        }
    });


    function highlightSubtitle(currentTime) {
        var formattedTime = currentTime

        // Find the nearest subtitle to the current time
        var nearestIndex = -1;
        var minDifference = Infinity;
        for (var i = 0; i < subtitles.length; i++) {
            var starting = parseTime(subtitles[i].start);
            var end = parseTime(subtitles[i].end);
            var difference = Math.min(Math.abs(starting - currentTime), Math.abs(end - currentTime));
            if (difference < minDifference) {
                minDifference = difference;
                nearestIndex = i;
            } else {
                break; // No need to check further
            }
        }


        // remove all highlights from other subtitles (if you want)
        subtitleDisplay.querySelectorAll(".sentence").forEach(elem => elem.classList.remove("highlight"))


        // Highlight the nearest subtitle
        var element = subtitleDisplay.querySelector("[data-subtitle-index='" + nearestIndex + "'] .sentence")
        element.classList.add("highlight")

        
    }



    displaySubtitles();




</script>




Thank you for taking the time to help me!!
